# How to fix when run "flutter doctor --android-licenses"?

Tags: android, flutter

When I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I got error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

How do I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replacing OpenJDK 11 with OpenJDK 8 currently fixes the problem for me. For example:

```
sudo apt autoremove openjdk-11-*
sudo apt purge openjdk-11-*

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux use the below command

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

In case of Windows use the below one:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee
```

***Note:***

This doesn't work for `Java 11+`, which doesn't have `Java` EE modules. For this I recommend to downgrade your `Java version` or wait for a `Flutter update`.

Comment: What's the java version you're using?

Comment: ```> java -version

openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: This is my java version

Comment: When I run `flutter doctor --android-license` again. I got `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
`